# What does the SegWit2MB proposal agreed upon at Consensus 2017 entail for the bitcoin network?

Tags: segregated-witness

From what I've read, I know this proposal is the combination of a hardfork to 2MB blocks with the activation of SegWit, but I haven't actually seen the code for this proposal to understand what the activation conditions are and what exactly happens and when. If this proposal were activated, what exactly would happen to the bitcoin network?